# Encountered an error during clang make: no such file or directory on ".#"

Tags: opencv

An error occurred when the procedure was executing the clang command, see below:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles/visp_gui.dir/src/display/.#vpDisplayOpenCV.cpp.o'
make[2]: *** [lib/libvisp_gui.3.0.0.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/gui/CMakeFiles/visp_gui.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I was wondering if there's any option I can do to set up in order to eliminate the `.#` prefix from the name of `vpDisplayOpenCV.cpp.o`.